# PowerPivot: get latest (date-based) record in table

Tags: powerquery, powerpivot

I am trying to do some analysis on PowerPivot.

I have mainly 2 tables.

1. List of Companies and Total number of employees

| Company | Total number of employees |
| --- | --- |
| Company A | 50 |
| Company B | 10 |

2. And a "Transaction" Table about a migration, it lists how many employees were migrated on a specific date. See below. On 10.10.22 1 employee of Company A was migrated on 11.10.22 in total 2 employees were migrated. So it's always the total. And on 16.10.22 the total was 4 so 1 less than on the 15.10.22 (yeah can happen)

| Company | Total Migrated employees | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | 1 | 10.10.22 |
| Company A | 2 | 11.10.22 |
| Company A | 5 | 15.10.22 |
| Company A | 4 | 16.10.22 |
| Company B | 1 | 15.10.22 |
| Company B | 2 | 16.10.22 |

At the end I want a table showing the progress in %, so something like this

| Company | Total number of employees | Total Migrated (last day) | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | 50 | 4 | 8% |
| Company B | 10 | 2 | 20% |

Any direction really appreciated.
I am thinking about Calculate and some kind of oldest function...

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Unclear to me if you want powerquery or powerpivot since you tagged both of them, but this is powerquery (M)

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source,"Total Migrated (last day)",(i)=>Table.Sort(Table.SelectRows(Table2, each [Company]=i[Company]),{{"Date", Order.Descending}})[Total Migrated employees]{0},type number),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "%", each [#"Total Migrated (last day)"]/[Total number of employees],Percentage.Type)
in #"Added Custom1"
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - I am trying to use Excel PowerPivot. Can I reuse your code in PowerPivot as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Found this - which is just what I needed:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hidJ5T_DYQ0

Comment: Thats a powerquery not powerpivot video.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).